# Hadoop cluster stops after mapping

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a hadoop cluster consisting of three machines. I put on hadoop 20 G file, I start hadoop and it stops after mapping.

"13/08/22 08:09:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 11%"

After mapping all cpu don't work. I can wait one day, but it can't start again.

What can I do?

This is last 10 lines of my log file, when map is 100% and reduce is 11%:

2013-08-22 14:15:32,503 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
2013-08-22 14:15:32,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 67
2013-08-22 14:15:32,552 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 68 sorted segments
2013-08-22 14:15:32,558 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 5 intermediate segments out of a total of 68
2013-08-22 14:15:32,622 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 64 segments left of total size: 1600710 bytes
2013-08-22 14:15:32,708 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task:attempt_201308221308_0002_m_000302_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
2013-08-22 14:15:32,717 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_201308221308_0002_m_000302_0' done.
2013-08-22 14:15:32,759 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2013-08-22 14:15:32,774 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO: Initialized cache for UID to User mapping with a cache timeout of 14400 seconds.
2013-08-22 14:15:32,774 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO: Got UserName llobocki for UID 1000 from the native implementation

My Child of master hadoop thread dump, when map is 100% and reduce is 11%:

```
 2013-08-23 11:37:26
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000f85800 nid=0x3873 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Thread for polling Map Completion Events" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc32860c800 nid=0x1d7a waiting on condition [0x00007fc31c183000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$GetMapEventsThread.run(ReduceTask.java:2882)

"Thread for merging in memory files" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc32860a800 nid=0x1d78 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc31c284000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd6dd7c8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$ShuffleRamManager.waitForDataToMerge(ReduceTask.java:1197)
    - locked <0x00000005bd6dd7c8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$InMemFSMergeThread.run(ReduceTask.java:2760)

"Thread for merging on-disk files" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc328608000 nid=0x1d77 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc31c385000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd713988> (a java.util.TreeSet)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$LocalFSMerger.run(ReduceTask.java:2654)
    - locked <0x00000005bd713988> (a java.util.TreeSet)

"MapOutputCopier attempt_201308230927_0001_r_000000_0.4" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc328606800 nid=0x1d76 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc31c486000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd762eb0> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.run(ReduceTask.java:1324)
    - locked <0x00000005bd762eb0> (a java.util.ArrayList)

"MapOutputCopier attempt_201308230927_0001_r_000000_0.3" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc328602000 nid=0x1d75 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc31c587000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd762eb0> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.run(ReduceTask.java:1324)
    - locked <0x00000005bd762eb0> (a java.util.ArrayList)

"MapOutputCopier attempt_201308230927_0001_r_000000_0.2" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc328600000 nid=0x1d73 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc31c688000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd762eb0> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.run(ReduceTask.java:1324)
    - locked <0x00000005bd762eb0> (a java.util.ArrayList)

"MapOutputCopier attempt_201308230927_0001_r_000000_0.1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc3285ff000 nid=0x1d72 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc31c789000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd762eb0> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.run(ReduceTask.java:1324)
    - locked <0x00000005bd762eb0> (a java.util.ArrayList)

"MapOutputCopier attempt_201308230927_0001_r_000000_0.0" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc3285f8800 nid=0x1d70 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc31c88a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd762eb0> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.run(ReduceTask.java:1324)
    - locked <0x00000005bd762eb0> (a java.util.ArrayList)

"communication thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc3285d2000 nid=0x1d53 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc31c9b3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd762e90> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$TaskReporter.run(Task.java:658)
    - locked <0x00000005bd762e90> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

"Timer for 'ReduceTask' metrics system" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc3285b1000 nid=0x1d49 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc31cbb5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd919a30> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x00000005bd919a30> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Thread for syncLogs" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc328494000 nid=0x1d3e waiting on condition [0x00007fc31cebd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$3.run(Child.java:139)

"IPC Client (47) connection to /127.0.0.1:35127 from job_201308230927_0001" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc328492800 nid=0x1d3d in Object.wait() [0x00007fc31cfbe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd721b60> (a org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.waitForWork(Client.java:747)
    - locked <0x00000005bd721b60> (a org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:789)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc3280f4000 nid=0x1cf7 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc3280f1800 nid=0x1cf5 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc3280ee800 nid=0x1cf4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc3280ec800 nid=0x1cf3 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc32809e000 nid=0x1ce5 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc2c1b7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd6fb1f8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000005bd6fb1f8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc32809c000 nid=0x1ce4 in Object.wait() [0x00007fc2c1c80000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005bd6fade8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000005bd6fade8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc32800b000 nid=0x1cc8 waiting on condition [0x00007fc32dc3a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier.fetchOutputs(ReduceTask.java:2191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc328094800 nid=0x1cdf runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc328018800 nid=0x1ccc runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc32801a800 nid=0x1cce runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc32801c800 nid=0x1cd7 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc32801e000 nid=0x1cd8 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fc3280fe800 nid=0x1cf8 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 224
```

During mapping the net traffic is ~20 MiB on master, but when reduce starts, net traffic goes down to 3 KiB.

> iostat

of my machines.

Master during map:

```
 Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    7.00     0.00     0.02     6.29     0.48   68.43  68.29  47.80
sda               0.00     0.00   43.00    7.00     5.38     0.02   221.04     0.22    4.42   2.78  13.90
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00   43.00    3.00     5.38     0.01   239.83     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Filesystem:               rMB_nor/s    wMB_nor/s    rMB_dir/s    wMB_dir/s    rMB_svr/s    wMB_svr/s     ops/s    rops/s    wops/s

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00    14.00    0.00   53.00     0.00     1.34    51.66     1.58   29.77   5.38  28.50
sda               3.00    14.00   34.00   53.00     4.62     1.34   140.34     1.27   14.55   3.84  33.40
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00   37.00   62.00     4.62     1.32   122.99     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Slave during map:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               2.00     0.00   12.00    4.00     1.75     0.01   225.25     0.76   47.50  25.19  40.30
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    6.00     0.00     0.02     6.00     0.09   20.00  14.67   8.80
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00   14.00    2.00     1.75     0.01   225.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Filesystem:               rMB_nor/s    wMB_nor/s    rMB_dir/s    wMB_dir/s    rMB_svr/s    wMB_svr/s     ops/s    rops/s    wops/s

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00   28.00    4.00     3.50     0.01   224.81     0.39   12.28   7.16  22.90
sdb               0.00     0.00    5.00    3.00     0.42     0.01   110.25     0.25   31.50  22.12  17.70
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00   33.00    0.00     3.92     0.00   243.39     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Master stopped:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00     0.00    8.00    1.00     1.00     0.00   228.44     0.03    3.44   3.00   2.70
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    1.00     0.00     0.00     8.00     0.01   13.00  13.00   1.30
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00    8.00    0.00     1.00     0.00   256.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Filesystem:               rMB_nor/s    wMB_nor/s    rMB_dir/s    wMB_dir/s    rMB_svr/s    wMB_svr/s     ops/s    rops/s    wops/s

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00     0.00    8.00    0.00     1.00     0.00   256.00     0.01    0.62   0.50   0.40
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00    8.00    0.00     1.00     0.00   256.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Filesystem:               rMB_nor/s    wMB_nor/s    rMB_dir/s    wMB_dir/s    rMB_svr/s    wMB_svr/s     ops/s    rops/s    wops/s

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00     0.00    8.00    0.00     1.00     0.00   256.00     0.02    2.38   2.38   1.90
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00    8.00    0.00     1.00     0.00   256.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Filesystem:               rMB_nor/s    wMB_nor/s    rMB_dir/s    wMB_dir/s    rMB_svr/s    wMB_svr/s     ops/s    rops/s    wops/s

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00     0.00    8.00    0.00     1.00     0.00   256.00     0.01    0.75   0.50   0.40
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00    8.00    0.00     1.00     0.00   256.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Slave stopped:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    8.00    0.00     1.00     0.00   256.00     0.01    1.38   1.12   0.90
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00    8.00    0.00     1.00     0.00   256.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Filesystem:               rMB_nor/s    wMB_nor/s    rMB_dir/s    wMB_dir/s    rMB_svr/s    wMB_svr/s     ops/s    rops/s    wops/s

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    7.00    0.00     0.88     0.00   256.00     0.01    0.71   0.57   0.40
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00    7.00    0.00     0.88     0.00   256.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Filesystem:               rMB_nor/s    wMB_nor/s    rMB_dir/s    wMB_dir/s    rMB_svr/s    wMB_svr/s     ops/s    rops/s    wops/s

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    8.00    0.00     1.00     0.00   256.00     0.01    0.75   0.62   0.50
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md1               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00    8.00    0.00     1.00     0.00   256.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Comment: May be you have outrun your reducer memory or disk space. How many reducers are you using?

Comment: I have default settings. Can I change file "conf/mapred-site.xml"?

Comment: Go on, make sure you have sufficient memory and disk space in each of the tasktracker running nodes.

Comment: Each node has 30 G RAM and 1,5 T free space. When reduce stops, cpu don't work, using RAM - 1,5%.

Comment: do you have reduce task failures? Please check the logs.

Comment: On my own PC, I have a single-node hadoop cluster. I have the same problem with big file (bigger than 7 G).

Comment: Yeah, can you post your reduce side code? It seems something is wrong in your reducer. I'm not sure though.

Comment: I test my cluster and I use jar $HADOOP_HOME/examples-1.1.2.jar, class wordcount.
But when I use mahout and I try make user similarity, I have the same problem during reduce.

Comment: I'm out of ideas for the time being. Will get back to you later. Or, someone else might answer your question. Please update your question to have more details in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks. I will paste my conf/*.xml

Comment: Anything interesting in the logs?

Comment: I've added my log file. I have to use Ctrl+C.

Comment: Take a threaddump of your reducer please.

Comment: Only RunJar thread dump?

Comment: A threaddump of your running reducer process anything else is useless.

Comment: OK. I've added Child.

Comment: It is still copying data, how fast is your disk? Do you see the disk working (e.g. with `iostat`)?

Comment: I've added iostat of my machines.

Comment: Hadoop is still running. On master and slave 1 Child switched off. But on slave 2 Child is still running.

Comment: When I run analysis on a single-node cluster everything is OK. But on a multi-node cluster it stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem. I had an incorrect value in /etc/hosts.

Earlier:

```
ip alias
```

Now:

```
ip domain alias
```